# Single Threaded vs Multithreaded, Should I even be concerned with converting to Multithreaded?

Tags: multithreading, macos

I have an application that ingests 32 live audio streams, encodes/compresses them, and sends them out via network, running on OSX (10.8.x).  Profiling shows that most of the CPU time is spent in the compressor/encoder functions, and Activity Monitor shows about a 40% CPU utilization.  The application works fine single-threaded, it just hogs one processor core quite a bit.

Just for fun, I implemented a bunch of concurrent dispatch queues to make use of multi-core processing, and now do most of the encoding in parallel.  Activity Monitor shows that I'm now fairly evenly distributed over the CPU's, but of course I'm still using the same percentage of the overall CPU capacity (in fact, slightly more due to the GCD overhead).

The only real advantage is that the audio packets in the multithreaded case get transmitted about 4ms sooner than in the single threaded case, but this isn't really a big deal in the overall system performance.

So the question is this: Given the fact that the application runs 'OK' single threaded, is there any other benefits to not hogging one processor?  Assuming we had a 4 core processor, is it better or worse to use 40% of one core, or 10% of four cores?  Math would say that this is the same.

OR, am I just beating myself up over nothing?

Thanks,

Chuck

Comment: well now that you have it working in parallel shouldn't you be able to stress test it. see if there is any advantage? intuitively you should be more resilient to transient load on the system now, right?

Comment: The problem is that the system still seems quite zippy (completely subjective observation) whether or not the application is single/multi-threaded.  I'm trying to get my head around whether or not there are any hidden benefits to spreading the load over multiple cores, given that there is enough bandwidth to handle the problem either way.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're using less than 100% of one core, there isn't much advantage to multithreading it.

OTOH, it's likely that not all of your users have a Mac that is as fast as yours.  If your program ever gets run on a slower (yet still multicore) Mac, where the single-thread would pin a core at 100%, then multithreading would speed things up on that Mac.